# Sorting IList<Specific_Object_Type>

Tags: c#, .net, ilist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting an IList in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486/sorting-an-ilist-in-c-sharp)

I have an `IList<Keyword>` where Keyword is a class containing a title(string) and a key(number). I wish to sort this IList based on the key. Is there an inbuilt C# functionality that I can use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486/sorting-an-ilist-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add: `using System.Linq;`

```
IList<keyword> sortedList = list.OrderBy(r => r.key).ToList();
```

Or you can try:

```
  IList<keyword> sortedList2 = (from r in list
                                orderby r.key
                                select r).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was missing the using. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
You can use `OrderBy` or`OrderByDescending`

```
var sort = list.OrderBy(x=> x.key);
```

Or

```
var reverseSort = list.OrderByDescending(x=> x.key);
```

Comment: There is no sort method for IList.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855) which you can use if you have `IList<YourType>` or `IEnumerable<YourType>`.

```
 var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(x=> x.key);
```

Comment: intelisense doesn't show any orderby method with IList.

Comment: @user1314871 Are you using .NET pre-3.5 or C# pre-3.0? If so, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linq Enumerable.OrderBy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)  for this:

```
var result = listOfObject.OrderBy(item => item.key).ToList();
```

for sorting in descending order use [Enumerable.OrderByDescending Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-u/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending)..

If you are using .net framework 3.0 and above then include `using System.Linq`  on top and try above extension method.

Comment: intelisense doesn't show any orderby method with IList

Comment: you should add using System.Linq for intelisense

Answer (score 0):

Yes with help of extension method you can easily achieve this

```
var sortelist = list.OrderBy(x=>x.PropertyName).ToList();
```

MSDN :

To sort data Ascending :

[Enumerable.OrderBy Method (IEnumerable, Func)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) - Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a key.

To sort data Descending :

[Enumerable.OrderByDescending Method (IEnumerable, Func)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx) - Sorts the elements of a sequence in descending order according to a key.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using dynamic = System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Lib.Extensions
{
    public static class Utils
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sorts by Model property with dynamic expression
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="list"> </param>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        /// <param name="sortDirection"> </param>
public static List<TObject> SortByModelProperty<TObject, TProperty>(this List<TObject> list, Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> property, SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        string propertyName = GetPropertyName(property);
        string exp1 = string.Format("model.{0}", propertyName);

        var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TObject), "model");
        var e1 = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p1 }, null, exp1);

        if (e1 != null)
        {
            if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                var result = list.OrderBy((Func<TObject, TProperty>)e1.Compile()).ToList();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = list.OrderByDescending((Func<TObject, TProperty>)e1.Compile()).ToList();
                return result;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName<TObject, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> property)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;

        return propertyInfo.Name;
    }

    }
}
```

You should add System.Linq.Dynamic.You can find it Nuget package manager.
 I think that This extension method helps you.

Comment: It's usage is very easy. Example yourlist.SortByModelProperty(x=>x.PropertyName,SortDirection.Ascending)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sorted = from c in list orderby c.Key select c;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have control over the `Keyword` class and consider the number ordering its "natural" ordering, have `Keyword` implement the `IComparable<Keyword>` interface.

If you don't have control over the class or you don't want to specify this ordering as natural/default, create a class which implements the `IComparator<Keyword>` interface.

EDIT: Or use LINQ for a simpler, quicker answer. Been stuck in Java too long!

```
var sorted = keywords.OrderBy(k => k.Key);
```