# Ordering a System.Collections.IList

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, ilist

Is it possible to order a System.Collection.IList without casting it to a known type?

I'm receiving a list as `object` and casting it to a IList using

```
var listType = typeof(List<>);
var cListType = listType.MakeGenericType(source.GetType());
var p = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(cListType);
var s = (IList)source;
```

and I want to order it based on Id which may or may not be available.

What I want to procude is something like:

```
if (s.First().GetType().GetProperties().where(m=>m.Name.Contians("Id")).FirstOrDefault != null)
{
     s=s.OrderBy(m=>m.Id);
}
```

However, s does not have the extension method "Order" and neither have the extension method "First"

Comment: How do you want to order things if you don't even know what you order???

Comment: no its not possible withoud generics or without writing your own extension methos afaik. but what you could do, is casting it to object that would work with your reflection solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486/sorting-an-ilist-in-c-sharp

Comment: What exactly do you want to order these unknown objects by if you don't know what they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next code. It will not sort if there is no `id` property on your `source` type

```
void Main()
{
    var source = typeof(Student);

    var listType = typeof(List<>);
    var cListType = listType.MakeGenericType(source);
    var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(cListType);

    var idProperty = source.GetProperty("id");

    //add data for demo
    list.Add(new Student{id = 666});
    list.Add(new Student{id = 1});
    list.Add(new Student{id = 1000});

    //sort if id is found
    if(idProperty != null)
    {
        list = list.Cast<object>()
                   .OrderBy(item => idProperty.GetValue(item))
                   .ToList();
    }

    //printing to show that list is sorted
    list.Cast<Student>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.id));
}

class Student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

prints:

```
1
666
1000
```